# Google Cloud Translation API error in server

Tags: google-cloud-platform

My application uses Google Cloud Translation API for language translation. The API works fine when I run my application in local PC but when **I deploy it into the server the translation API throws me the below error**,

```
Mar 21 04:42:07 chatbot-app2 gunicorn[61109]:   
<p>Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/language/translate/v2</code> from this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

This only happens in the server, and I have updated my curl versions as I have seen in a previous solution but nothing works

Answer (score 0):

I see that there has been some disruption to both Agent Assist and Speech-to-Text in the Americas, Europe, and Asia Pacific regions, according to the Service Health dashboard. I can't confirm if this is the exact issue you're experiencing, but it's worth checking out [here](https://status.cloud.google.com/#:%7E:text=Access%20Transparency-,Agent%20Assist,-AI%20Platform%20Prediction).

Comment: Thanks Narayan. I just checked the health for cloud translation, but its globally available.